# CNN filter for music spectrograms

Tags: deep-learning, keras, audio-recognition

I am new to Data science and I am trying to build a neural Network to recognise Musical Instruments .. I am Kind lost here on how to choose the CNN filter size ?

Comment: Start with the pretrained arch's, just fine-tune and see how they are performing first; For selecting filter_size, start with 3 and go linearly upto 5 maybe; Also are you using the Audio to determine the instrument?

Comment: Just to get the idea of a general setup that works, check out https://github.com/keunwoochoi/music-auto_tagging-keras and the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.00298.pdf The approach was originally meant for general auto tagging, but will also work for instruments. A more current (and complicated) approach using attention is presented in http://archives.ismir.net/ismir2019/paper/000007.pdf